My render is coming out blurry and I don't know why
Recently I've been trying to render a scene I created. Previously, it had rendered the scene fine but when I tried making a clay render today, it came out looking blurry like an oil painting.

I looked up answers online and some said to turn off denoiser in the Render properties which I did but the final render ended up looking like a bunch of scattered dots instead of a full image. Another mentioned increasing the render samples but it still came out looking the same. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Some more screenshots of my settings:



Looks like denoise artifacts, the scene looks very dark and you probably gonna need more samples than 4096. Also, is there any reason to use "Feature Experimental"?

Indeed it looks like denoising artifacts, although I've had better results with a lot less than 4096 samples (I rarely use more than 500 or 1000). What are your Light Paths settings? And have you tried with increasing the lights a lot? You can always reduce the exposure if the scene gets too bright.

You may need to post your blend file.  The symptoms you describe (bad denoising and scattered dots when it's turned off) occur with very dark scenes and highly indirect light, but your environment looks plenty bright.  If the window is a material rather than a hole in the wall, I would suspect there's something wrong with its settings.
